# Current udp packets queue length

Tags: udp, queue

I have rather simple UDP server written on c.
Sometimes i need to know current length of all udp packets(bytes) queued in socket.
As i understand, getsockopt doesn't get such information.

Linux and FreeBSD solutions are both welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`ioctl(FIONREAD, ...)` should be roughly what you are looking for,

http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/ioctl.2.html

Comment: Actually this does not work on linux. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278189/how-do-i-get-amount-of-queued-data-for-udp-socket

Answer (score 1):

From outside of the server (command line), you can do

`netstat -uln`

which will show you the length of all listening udp sockets.