# How do I get amount of queued data for UDP socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

To see how well I'm doing in processing incoming data, I'd like to measure the queue length at my TCP and UDP sockets.

I know that I can get the queue size via `SO_RCVBUF` socket option, and that `ioctl(<sockfd>, SIOCINQ, &<some_int>)` tells me the information for TCP sockets. But for UDP the `SIOCINQ`/`FIONREAD` ioctl returns only the size of next pending datagram. Is there a way how to get queue size for UDP, without having to parse system tables such as `/proc/net/udp`?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't get this information directly since the kernel doesn't support it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ldx mentioned, it is not supported through ioctl or getsockopt.
It seems to me that the current implementation of SIOCINQ was aimed to determine how much buffer is needed to read the entire waiting buffer (but I guess it is not so useful for that, as it can change between the read of it to the actual buffer read).

There are many other telemetries which are not supported though such system calls, I guess there is no real need in normal production usage.

You can check the drops/errors through "netstat -su" , or better using SNMP (udpInErrors) if you just want to monitor the machine state.

BTW: You always have the option to hack in the Kernel code and add this value (or others).

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, I did some experiments to map out the behavior of `FIONREAD` on different platforms.

Platforms where `FIONREAD` returns all the data pending in a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket:

> Mac OS X, NetBSD, FreeBSD, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Windows

Platforms where `FIONREAD` returns only the bytes for the first pending datagram:

> Linux

It might also be worth noting that some implementations include headers or other overhead bytes in the count, while others only count the payload bytes.  Linux appears to return the payload size, not including IP headers.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work, per [udp(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/udp.7.html): _"FIONREAD (SIOCINQ): Returns the size of the next pending datagram in the integer in bytes, or 0 when no datagram is pending."_

Comment: My bad: I forgot that `FIONREAD` works differently on Linux than it does on the *BSDs and Solaris.  I will edit my answer to show the platform differences.