# What does FIONREAD of UDP (datagram) sockets return?

Tags: networking, udp, datagram, ioctl

Which one does `ioctl` of `FIONREAD` return, the next packet's length, or the length of all data in the buffer?

Suppose there is a `UDP` server that receives 2 packets from a client 1 and another 2 packets from client 2 after client 1's packet.
Then, what is the value of `ioctl` of `FIONREAD`, 
and what does `readfrom` return in that case?

Client 1 : v two packets

++UDP Server got 4 packets <- FIONREAD?

Client 2 : ^ two packets

[image]

### FIONREAD? (server)

1. length of client 1's first packet
2. length of client 1's two packets
3. length of client 1's two packets + client 2's two packets
4. length of client 1's first packet + client 2's first packet
5. other

Comment: Hello! Checkout the new answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[man udp (7)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=udp&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) states:

> ```
>    FIONREAD (SIOCINQ)
>           Gets a pointer to an integer as argument.  Returns the  size  of
>           the  next pending datagram in the integer in bytes, or 0 when no
>           datagram is pending.  Warning: Using FIONREAD, it is  impossible
>           to  distinguish  the  case where no datagram is pending from the
>           case where the next pending  datagram  contains  zero  bytes  of
>           data.   It  is  safer  to use select(2), poll(2), or epoll(7) to
>           distinguish these cases.
> ```

So, the answer to your question is: **FIONREAD returns the size of the next (first) pending datagram**.

Comment: So you mean the whole packet's size or just the data in the datagram packet?

Comment: @jinoh67 I'm not quite sure about it, since man-pages don't say it explicitly, but I'm going to find it out experimentally today.

Comment: @jinoh67 I've just checked it: on my Debian 7 `FIONREAD` returns the size of data contained in datagram (datagram message size).

Answer (score 3):

It is platform-dependent.

- On some platforms, FIONREAD on a UDP socket returns the size of the first datagram.
- On others it returns the total number of bytes that can be read without blocking, which is the total number of bytes presently in the socket receive buffer.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296481/207421) for further information.

The return value of `recvfrom()` is the actual number of bytes transferred.

Comment: So you mean 3 is correct for FIONREAD, and 2 (length of packet) for recvfrom? (I use non-blocking socket, of course)

Comment: I meant what I said, and it applies to both UDP and TCP using the wording I provided.

Comment: I am not sure that you answer is correct for a UDP socket. Do you have any references to `FIONREAD returns the total number of bytes that can be read without blocking`. I've posted an answer with a reference to a different information.

Comment: @Kolyunya We're both right, see edit.