# ioctl with FIONREAD return value

Tags: c++, sockets, berkeley-sockets

This question is related to [What does FIONREAD of udp socket return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995766/what-does-fionread-of-udp-socket-returns)

I tried to use next code on Mac:

```
if( ioctl(socketId, FIONREAD, &totalPending) == -1 )
{
    printf("%d", totalPending);
}

numBytesRecv = recvfrom(socketId, buffer, maxLen, 0, socketAddress, &socketAddressLen);
```

On every call where `numBytesRecv != 0`, `numBytesRecv == totalPending - 16`

Can you please explain me why this happens? Is this return value correct? If yes, may I assume `numBytesRecv == totalPending - 16` for every value `numBytesRecv != 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278189/how-do-i-get-amount-of-queued-data-for-udp-socket), `FIONREAD` on a Mac returns the size of all available data in the socket's receive buffer, NOT the size of the next pending message.  `recvfrom()` reports the size of just the payload of a received message.  So what you are likely seeing is simply `FIONREAD` reporting additional bytes in the socket's receive buffer that are related to messages after the next pending message.  If you need to know the size of the next pending message, use `FIONREAD` to know *when* to call `recvfrom()`, but don't rely on `FIONREAD` to tell you the actual message size.  Instead, call `recvfrom()` with the `MSG_PEEK` flag and a large data buffer. The return value will tell you the message size.  You can then call `recvfrom()` again without the `MSG_PEEK` flag to receive the message and remove it from the receive buffer.